# can't access rvm from ruby script after install, trouble with source .bashrc

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm

I am trying to install ruby 1.9.2 from a ruby script using rvm which is installed from the same script.  The problem I have is sourcing .bashrc within the script so that the path to rvm is available within the script.    The following works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

%x[bash -c "bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)" ]
%x[ln -s /usr/local/rvm/ .rvm]
%x[echo "[[ -s \"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm\" ]] && source \"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm\""  >> ~/.bashrc]
```

But I am not able to execute from within this ruby script

```
 source .bashrc
```

I've tried

```
  %x[bash -c "bash <(. .bashrc)"]
```

I've also tried running separately the line that the script added to .bashrc

```
 %x[ bash -c "bash <(source  \"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm\" )"   ]
```

I have tried sessions but the puts below gives a blank response to "which rvm".

```
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'session'
 bash = Session::Bash.new
 stdout, stderr = bash.execute 'source .bashrc'
 puts "which rvm = " + %x[which rvm 2>&1].inspect
```

Am I looking at this all wrong?  Is trying to source .bashrc within a ruby script and using the resulting environment to execute subsequent commands possible?

**Update -**

Using Ian's approach below with bash -ic I was able to get the ruby script working.  But all subsequent shell commands that need to see the new environment have to be run with bash -ic as well.  Here is the working script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby
 %x[bash -c "bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)" ]
 %x[ln -s /usr/local/rvm/ .rvm]
 %x[echo "[[ -s \"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm\" ]] && source \"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm\""  >> ~/.bashrc]
 %x[bash -ic "bash <(. ~/.bashrc); rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p290; rvm 1.9.2-p290 --default;"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to pass the `-l` flag to the invocation of bash from ruby, which will make the embedded bash shell act as a login shell and read `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`. See also the [ref manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files) for more details.

**Update**

Sorry, I meant the `-i` flag, not `-l`. I tried this:

```
[~/temp/rubytest] 
ian@ian-desktop2 $ echo "export FOO=fubar" >> ~/.bashrc
[~/temp/rubytest] 
ian@ian-desktop2 $ irb
jruby-1.6.5 :001 > %x[ bash -c "env | grep FOO" ]
 => "" 
jruby-1.6.5 :003 > %x[ bash -ic "env | grep FOO" ]
 => "FOO=fubar\n" 
jruby-1.6.5 :004 > %x[ bash -ic "echo 'export FOO2=fubar2' >> ~/.bashrc ; env | grep FOO" ]
 => "FOO=fubar\n" 
jruby-1.6.5 :005 > %x[ bash -ic "echo 'export FOO2=fubar2' >> ~/.bashrc ; source /home/ian/.bashrc ; env | grep FOO" ]
 => "FOO=fubar\nFOO2=fubar2\n" 
jruby-1.6.5 :006 >
```

Comment: Ian - thanks for your answer.  What you suggest makes sense, but I still can't get it to work.  I've tried %x[bash -c -l "bash <(source .bashrc)"] as well as `/bin/bash -c -l '. /root/.bashrc'` as well as a few others.  Can you post some code that you have tried which executes source .bashrc from within a ruby script and works?

Comment: Ian - Thanks so much, that rocks!   It appears that for all subsequent shell commands, if they want to see the new environment, they need to be run with bash -ic as well as I updated in my post.  But it all works!